# cannot pipe mp4 file in node.js

Tags: node.js

I am trying to pipe an mp4 file in my root directory to but I cannot get it to work, it start buffering for streaming but never plays the file.

here is my code

```
var http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(),
    fs = require('fs'),
    rs = fs.createReadStream('./Practice/Jumanji.mp4');
server.on('request', function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'video/mp4'
    });
    rs.pipe(res);
    res.end();
});
server.listen(4000);
```

The movie tries to load but never does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems in your code that I see

1. Streams are one-time use objects, so once you fetch one video, a second request would fail because the stream was already closed. Your `rs = fs.createReadStream('./Practice/Jumanji.mp4');` line should be inside the callback.
2. Likely the cause of your error in this case, is `res.end();`. That will immediately close `res` before your pipe has had time to write the video, so you are essentially saying `"Send this stream"` followed immediately by `"Send nothing"`. You should delete that line, since the pipe will automatically close `res` when all the data is written.

All this said, there is a lot of error handling logic that your example is missing, which you may want to consider.

Comment: thanks a lot I now see the obvious errors, I  am just starting node.js, it will get better in no time.